# The two-body problem: What is force between them?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

Two bodies with similar/different mass orbiting around a common barycenter.

- What is force between them, where $F_{12}$ is the force on mass 1 due to its interactions with mass 2 and $F_{21}$ is the force on mass 2 due to its interactions with mass 1?
- What is relation between $F_{12}$ and $F_{21}$?
- What is total force between them?

Comment: is there anybody out there!?

Comment: Newton say: "$F_{12}=-F_{21}$".

Comment: Did you do a search for two-body problem?

Comment: Suggest close exact duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6616/

Comment: Have a look at my asnwer to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29902/

Comment: This looks like (very easy) homework, except for "total force"--- I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 4):

According to Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation, the magnitude of the force between the two bodies can be calculated by the following equation:

$F$ = $G$*$m_{1}$*$m_{2}$/$r^2$

where:

$G$ is the gravitational constant
$m_{1}$ is the mass of the first body
$m_{2}$ is the mass of the second body
$r$ is the distance between the centers of the masses

As for the relation between the two forces, according to Newton's 3rd Law:

$F_{12}$ = $-F_{21}$

Answer (score 2):

This is given by [Newton's law of gravitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation):
$$F_{12} = F_{21} = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2},$$
where $G$ is the universal gravitational constant, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the two bodies, and $r$ is the distance between them. The two forces have equal magnitude but point in opposite directions. (That's [Newton's third law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion).)